# How can I correct superfluous new lines in footnotes when using Markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, footnotes

I am using Jekyll static site generator with Kramdown to render articles written in Markdown on my website. The footnotes appear fine in preview in Sublime Text Editor (text next to numbers) but have new lines when on website.

Compare [Website Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWDJo.png) vs
[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsCgW.png).

And here's the article with syntax I am using:

> As regards to a reasonable definition of a friend:
>
> `Proposition 1` : A minimum necessary condition for A to be considered a *friend* of B is that A helps when B is in need, as long as A knows that B needs help and it is in A's capacity to help. [^clarification1][^indeed
>
> [^clarification1]: For clarification, anyone who argues against
> Proposition 1 would have to maintain that A can consistently refuse to
> help B (when B is in need and it is in A's capacity to help without
> harming his/her own self interest), AND yet be a friend of B.

Comment: can you post the HTML source for the sections in the two images above?

Comment: This is certainly a css problem. But with no code, it's impossible to debug.

Comment: Since the code is auto-generated, even if I delve into the code and debug it, the next time it will spew out the same old auto-generated code, right?

The footnotes used to be fine about a year earlier, and I made no changes to the software, and now they're rendering incorrectly. Could this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your generated code.

In my versions of jekyll/kramdown I get...

```
<div class="footnotes">
    <ol>
       <li id="fn:1">
          <p>Your footnote text</p>
       </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Therefore, in your css you could add:

```
.footnotes > ol > li > p {
    display: inline;
}
```

The above CSS would stop the p tag, only after the footnote class in an ordered list element, from line-breaking.